# How to install unpublished Gmail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace-add-ons

We want to install *Unpublished* Gmail add-on which is under verification process.

It can be done by copying *app-scripts* files to our project but we wanted to search for the *Unpublished app* and install it for some testing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Edited my question